# Yii2 formatter date: сдвиг +1 час, откуда?

Tags: php, yii2

В `GridView` выводится `UNIX TIMESTAMP`, взятый из MySQL. Для вывода колонки используется вот такой параметр:

```
        [
            'attribute' => 'date',
            'filter'    => false,
            'format'    => ['date', 'php:d.m.Y H:i'],
        ],
```

По каким-то причинам на продакшн-сервере все вот такие колонки отображаются с поправкой +1 час, не смотря на то, что у сервера, у РНР и у MySQL часовой пояс - Москва. На тестовом сервере все ок. При этом функция `date()` форматирует время корректно. Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это проблема с версией intl ICU библиотека для php. Связано с переводом часов который был в России до 2012.
Если ее обновить будет работать корректно. Можно также просто отключить в php.ini ее, Но тогда некоторые функции не будут работать связанные с международным форматированием.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
['attribute' => 'date', 'value' => function ($value) {
   return \Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($value, "php:d.m.Y H:i");
}],
```

Comment: сделал тупо: `return date('d.m.Y H:i', $model->date);` нормально работает. Что-то перемудрили в yii2